# Reactjs @setState with a dynamic key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a dynamic object in props, which I want to send in state

```
@setState
  key: val
  values:
    another_key: value
    @props.data.option: @props.data.value
```

But this way does not work, I found this solution:

```
  newState = {}
  newState[@props.data.option] = @props.data.value
  this.setState(newState);
```

But this way sets the value of the right in state

Comment: Why are you storing an item passed in via `props` in `state`? If `props.data.value` is your single source of truth, why not just use that in your `render()` function or wherever else you need this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are dealing with nested objects in state, and the entire object `values` is replaced when it seems you only want to update a subset of the keys in the `values` object.  The best way to do this is to use React's immutability helpers via the `set` operation. (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

using es6, you can set a dynamic key:

```
var update = require('react-addons-update');

var newState = update(this.state, {
  values:  {[dynamic_key]: {$set: dynamic_value}}
});

this.setState(newState);
```

Comment: If I use in this way:

`var newState = update(this.state, {
  values:  {[@props.data.option]: {$set: @props.data.value}}
});
`

I got this error: `SyntaxError: [stdin]:200:17: unexpected [
`

Comment: I use the object initializer syntax from ECMAScript 2015 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).  The tool you use to transpile your react code may not support this syntax.

Comment: I would also suggest you pay attention to the concerns raised by  Calvin Belden above, as setting state from props is generally considered bad practice.